# Access SkyDrive Documents in WinRT

Tags: c#, wpf, windows-8.1

There are two documents folders in windows 8.1, one is at the root and the other one is located in SkyDrive Folder. Can anyone tell me that how can we access SkyDrive's Document Folder in Win 8.1 XAML/C# Application.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well you have two basic options. You can declare Documents capability and access them in KnownFolders.DocumentsLibrary or you can use Folder Picker.

If you use Documents capability you will get access to Documents library which includes SkyDrive(or any other folder linked to Documents Library) if you have it and if you have any data there. Important thing is that All Libraries has set default saving folder. SkyDrive automatically set itself as a default saving folder but it can be change in setting or in definition of Libraries. Another annoying thing is that you can access only files which type you declared before in manifest in file type association part. So its impossible to access all file types and the one you declare will be associated with your app which means your app will appear(or even be default) as app that open these files. This capability has also few validation problems. It appears that you need to buy External Validation Certificate to be able to pass validation process. And also its special capability that is restricted for now to Company accounts.

Because of previous mentioned constrains Document capability is not really useful(at least not in my eyes). So its better to use Folder picker and safe user chosen folder by StorageApplicationPermissions for later access without bothering user again. While using folder picker you can get to Documents and SkyDrive with more than one way. SkyDrive is in special menu. its also included in Documents Library under Library section. Or you can find it on your drive whenever you've chosen to have it. Separate Documets can be also find by choosing This PC and then folder Documents.

Comment: Thanks. I will implement this.

Comment: i am glad that i could help